# LeafletJS image overlay set bounds

Tags: angular, typescript, leaflet, ionic4, ngx-leaflet

I'm using [LeafletJS](https://leafletjs.com/) map. I need to use an image overlay. I have done it like so:

```
  onMapReady(event: any) {
     this.layers.push(imageOverlay(this.imgSrc + "map.png", [[35.334847, 25.328072], [35.337847, 25.339072]])); // This is the overlay
    }
```

I can see the small image overlay as below. But how can I show it the whole screen? I think the problem here is set bounds. But how can I set it? I have center  `"lat": "35.335847",`
        `"lon": "25.338072",` If this is the center (i.e. with arrow) then how can I show the image entire page? Any clue about how to set the bounds and find out those `lat` and `lon`?

***Note*** I use [ngx-leaflet](https://github.com/Asymmetrik/ngx-leaflet) here with Ionic 4

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like everything is fine apart from the coordinates, that you included in your code. To make your image overlay compatibile with the map please find some characteristic points on your image bound and get the coordinates from the map. Then fix them in your code doing it for North, East, South and West.[image]